# Spark: timestamp changes when reading from written file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a parquet that looks like :

```
------------ 
name | age | 
------------
Tom  | 12  | 
------------
Mary | 15  |
```

Now I added a column "timestamp" to it using :

```
final DataFrame dfWithNewColumn = df.withColumn("timestamp", createTimestamp())
```

and it looks like :

```
------------ --------------
name | age | timestamp     |
---------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 1569312845998 |
---------------------------
Mary | 15  | 1569312845998 |
```

And I write it into a parquet :

```
    dfWithNewColumn.write()
            .partitionBy(new String[]{"name","timestamp"})
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .parquet(parquetPath);
```

When I look it using spark-shell, it's in good format :

```
------------ --------------
name | age | timestamp     |
---------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 1569312845998 |
---------------------------
Mary | 15  | 1569312845998 |
```

But the problem is, when I read the parquet again :

```
public static StructType createSchema() {
    final StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
            DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.LongType, false)
    ));
    return schema;
}


    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .schema(createSchema())
            .parquet(parquetPath);
```

When I show the rows `df.show()`, it becomes :

```
------------ --------------
age | name | timestamp     |
---------------------------
12  | Tom  | 171798691853  |
---------------------------
15  | Mary  | 171798691853  |
```

How is that possible ? The parquet file is OK so I assume the problem is in the reading code.

Edit :

I found the cause. This problem happens after I changed spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled=false. How can I deal with it ?

Comment: try TimestampType instead of LongType

Comment: hi, do you think it's a problem with the schema ?

Comment: yep I think so. But I'm not sure, I didn't test it

Comment: i've tested, it's not working

Comment: now it shows "1970-01-03 00:43:..." in timestamp field when I read it from written parquet

Comment: can you print schema before writing your dataframe ?

Comment: hi, i confirm that this problem happens after I changed spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled=false

Comment: what could I do if I want to keep my timestamp as LongType ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Spark out of the box functions current_timestamp() which returns the current timestamp as a timestamp column. And for while reading it should be read as org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType datatype.

```
//Write 
final DataFrame dfWithNewColumn = df.withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())
//Read
public static StructType createSchema() {
final StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
        DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, false)
  ));
 return schema;
}
```